# Rolar UIscrollView automaticamente ao entrar no UItextField

Tags: ios, objective-c

Preciso criar um formulário que faça a tela rolar conforme ele vai sendo preenchido.
A ideia e que a tela role conforme vou preenchendo e assim exibindo os campos que estão abaixo do teclado.

Comment: Alex, colocou ios nas tags. Tem mais outra linguagem? JavaScript talvez? E já testou algum código? Poste pelo menos o seu HTML para a pergunta ser perceptivel. E bemvindo ao Stackoverflow!

Comment: Linguagem utilizada? Swift? Objective-C? HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Costumo utilizar um tableViewController com static cells. Quando o proximo se tornar firstResponder e ele estiver abaixo do teclado, a tableView sobe automaticamente.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    if ([textField isEqual:self.seuTextField]) {

        [self.proximoTextField becomeFirstResponder];

    }

    return YES;
}
```

Quando o usuário tocar no botão return de seu teclado, o próximo textField se torna o firstResponder.

Answer (score 2):

É bem fácil Alex. O que você precisa é verificar quando o determinado textfield começará a ser editado, e em seguida setar o contentOffset da sua scrollView. Como no exemplo abaixo:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{


    if ([textField isEqual:self.myTextField]) {

        [self.myScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 240) animated:YES];
    }

    return YES;

}
```

Lembre-se de setar o delegate do UITextField antes. Você pode fazer isso pelo storyBoard ou durante o viewDidLoad. Lembre-se também de sempre retornar YES, caso contrário o teclado não sobe. Boa Sorte!